# Balancing $du$ in $u$-substitution problem

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

I am solving the following problem using $u$-substitution:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{t+1}{2t^2+4t+3}dt$$

So $u$ = $2t^2+4t+3$ and $du$ = $4(t+1)dt$. However this does not exist in the equation so it must be balanced out. I am fairly certain that the problem ends up being something like this:

$$\int_3^9 \frac{1}{u} \frac{du}{4}$$ but I get confused as to how exactly the $t+1$ on top gets cancelled out.

Comment: Change it to $\int_0^1 \cfrac 1{2t^2+4t+3}\cdot(t+1)dt$. Can you see now?

Comment: That's exactly what I am asking. The basic math as to how those two are cancelled out is where I am getting confused. You have to even out the $4$ by multiplying by $\frac{1}{4}$ but if you also multiply by $t+1$ it doesn't end up cancelling out with the top? **Edit:** I missed that I am multiplying by $\frac{1}{t+1}$ and not just $t+1$.

Answer (score 1):

The $t + 1$ goes away when you make the substitution $dt = \frac{du}{4(t+1)}$ in your integrand. So,

$$
\int_0^1\frac{t+1}{2t^2+4t+3}\,dt = \int_3^9\frac{t+1}{u}\frac{du}{4(t+1)} = \int_3^9\frac{du}{4u}.
$$

Comment: Yea that's where I got confused. I was multiplying by $t+1$ instead of leaving it in the denominator or simply multiplying by $\frac{1}{t+1}$.